# "echo" session and logout in the same line

Tags: php, css

Currently when i showing my username(through session) and logout function , both of them is in different lines

Image: http://prntscr.com/nc2v1b  ( This is output )

What i want : https://prnt.sc/nc2w23

Username is on the right side of "Logout"

Comment: check the answer and accept the best solution, this will help to future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float right will push everything to the right (last item being the one the the most on the right).
Your code seem to work if you need to have everything on one line though.

```
<?php
session_start(); // Right at the top of your script
?>

<li class='active'>
 <?php 
 if($_SESSION['logged']==true)
 { 
     echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a>' . $_SESSION["username"];
 }
 else
 {
     echo '<a href="registerform.html"><span>Login/Register</span></a>';
 }

 echo '</li>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove this part `style='float:right;'`

Using `float:right` will move the text right.

Second, need some spacing here:

```
echo $_SESSION["username"]." "; // you can use `|` to separation 
echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></li>';
```